# Email Template not populating {!Contact.Name} with workflow Email Alert

Tags: workflow, email-template, email-alert

I have created an email template using `{!Contact.Name}` merge field to display conatct name. Object `XYZ__c` has a lookup field `MyContactLookup__c`. I have created workflow on object `XYZ__c` on record creation to send email. I have selected Related Contact - `MyContactLookup__c` as recipient. But when i create a record of that object with some selected contact, the email is sent to the same contact but does not display `CONTACT NAME`.

Please Help! I have tried it many times but it appears the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your **email template** and update the merge field to use `{!XYZ__c.MyContactLookup__c}` instead of `{!Contact.Name}`. I have just tested it and the email has **Contact name**, the lookup you would use on the `XYZ__c` object, properly filled.

Comment: What if i want to use Contact.FirstName?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. 1. Create a **formula** field on `xyx__c` object with `MyContactLookup__r.FirstName`. 2. and then edit your email template. This merge field should now be appearing against xyz__c object. 3. Insert this field and it will display only the firstname.